# TFS Build 2013 Failed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TFS build is failing when i try to trigger against a database hosted in 2016 version.
is this version compatibility issue? can we do some workaround for TFS 2013 to build.
below is the error message;

2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
*** Could not generate deployment script.
Unable to connect to target server.

below is the MSBuild Argument;

/p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=***Server_ip***;user id=***username***; Password=***password***" /p:TargetDatabase="***Database_name***" /p:DeploymentCollationPreference=DontChangeCollations

there is no change in IP/username/password these are valid.

Regards

Comment: Please try to login the build agent machine, and manually deploy to database from command line, to see how's the result. And share your build definition and what you want to achieve.

Comment: i sure will do this and get back.

Comment: How's the result?

Comment: @vivek, Not get your response for several days, would you please share us the latest information in your side? Could you build it successfully in your build agent machine? If you get any updates, feel free to share it. We will follow up it in time.

Comment: @cece, Apologies for late reply. i tried as u suggested and queued using cmd line, and i got error, Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (type NullReferenceException) Exception Stack Trace: at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: @vivek So, this seems not a TFS issue, it's your project issue. Generally if you cannot build the project locally, then it will also not work in TFS. Actually it calls the msbuild command when running in TFS, so please debug your project and make sure you can successfully run it on your local machine first.

Answer (score 0):

Check if a database connection exists between the TFS build agent and the database server
To check this, try with simple ping or create ODBC connection to the database with provided details (Connection string, username and password).
Hope it helps.